# websocket-sharp unity problem in OnMessage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, websocket

I'm producing a game
In the part of my game lobby, the list of openers in that room is received using the web socket
If the time interval is even 2 seconds between receiving the specifications, the work will be done without any problem, but if all the specifications are received at the same time, the MakeUILobby function will not work!

```
    public IEnumerator Start()
    {
        ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8081");
        ws.SetCookie();
        ws.Connect();
        WSConnectionStatus = true;
        ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
        {
            WSUserJoinedToRoom = JsonUtility.FromJson<WSUserJoinedToRoom>(e.Data);
            print("Message Received from " + ((WebSocket)sender).Url + ", Data : " + e.Data);
            _actions.Enqueue(() => MakeUILobby(WSUserJoinedToRoom.user_id, WSUserJoinedToRoom.user_name));
        };
    }

    private void MakeUILobby(string user_id, string user_name)
    {
        print(user_name);
    }
```

WebSocket Data Part1:

> {"user_id": "3", "user_name": "Player-3"}

WebSocket Data Part2:

> {"user_id": "1", "user_name": "Player-1"}

[image]

But if you look at the image above, the MakeUILobby function is called twice with the information of a player, if it should be like the image below!

[image]

Comment: I discovered this is the problem 
`_actions.Enqueue(() => . . .`
There is a problem when I use this, but when I do not use this, the game objects do not work.
`private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action> _actions = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();
void Update()
    {
        while (_actions.Count > 0)
        {
            if (_actions.TryDequeue(out var action))
            {
                action?.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is [value capturing in lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#capture-of-outer-variables-and-variable-scope-in-lambda-expressions).

The value of field `WSUserJoinedToRoom` is changed every time when receiving the last item so when the main thread frame playes it will execute both lambda actions which will both access the same `WSUserJoinedToRoom` value.

So in your case

- player 3 is received and stored into `WSUserJoinedToRoom` and you add the callback action
- player 1 is received and stored into `WSUserJoinedToRoom` and you add the callback action
- now the main thread executed Update and executes both actions which do read the `user_id` and `user_name` from the **current** `WSUserJoinedToRoom` (player 1), **not** the one it was when the callback was `Enqueue`d!

---

Instead either store the two strings in local variables before:

```
ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
{
    WSUserJoinedToRoom = JsonUtility.FromJson<WSUserJoinedToRoom>(e.Data);
    print("Message Received from " + ((WebSocket)sender).Url + ", Data : " + e.Data);
    // HERE: Store new variables for the values
    var userId = WSUserJoinedToRoom.user_id;
    var userName = WSUserJoinedToRoom.user_name;
    _actions.Enqueue(() => MakeUILobby(userId, userName));
};
```

Or simply don't use a field for `WSUserJoinedToRoom` at all but do

```
ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
{
    // HERE: Simply make a new variable everytime
    var WSUserJoinedToRoom = JsonUtility.FromJson<WSUserJoinedToRoom>(e.Data);
    print("Message Received from " + ((WebSocket)sender).Url + ", Data : " + e.Data);
    _actions.Enqueue(() => MakeUILobby(WSUserJoinedToRoom.user_id, WSUserJoinedToRoom.user_name));
};
```